# Running Eclipse JDT from sources

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-jdt

I want to run Eclipse Java Development Tools form source code, but I'm stuck after checking out codes from eclipse repositories.

I've checked out all plugins from **org.eclipse.jdt** and imported them into my workspace, but after this I'm stuck.

There is lot of errors so obviously there are dependencides missing, but I don't know what else is needed to import/install in order to make this work.

I've read tutorial by Lars Vogella about working with Eclipse source codes, but it only covers examination of codes.
http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html

Comment: Are you checking out JDT plug-ins in an Eclipse that contains JDT? If JDT is already installed on your Eclipse, you shouldn't get errors for missing dependencies when you checkout the source code of some JDT plug-ins.

Comment: Yes, I have JDT installed, but your remark gives me the idea that there might be version conflict. I've checked out head revisions, but I'm working on Eclipse 3.6 SR2, so this might be the reason. I'll check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Eclipse Classic Edition has the source-code of JDT and PDE integrated. After downloading and starting Eclipse Classic you can open the View "Plug-ins", select the JDT Plugins and select "Import as..." -> "Source Project" via Context-Menu

Comment: Since I don't need the newest sources available this is the most simple solution (I don't even need to check anything out from repo) and completely sufficient.

Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

Following up our discussion, you should make sure that the versions of the plug-ins you check out from the source repository are consistent with those installed on your Eclipse. You can check out the source code of your installed plug-ins by going to the plug-ins view, right-click on the JDT plug-ins and choose `Import As -> Project from a Repository...` and select `Import specific versions below`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to
- File > Import
- Plug-ins and fragments
- On the next screen under 'Import as' select 'Projects from repository'
- On next screen, use filter as 'org.eclipse.jdt' and import all the matching plugins.